# Will Google provide user information on SMS Authentication?

Tags: firebase-authentication

Using SMS authentication, the userCredential information returned by Google is:

UserCredential(additionalUserInfo: AdditionalUserInfo(isNewUser: false, profile: null, providerId: phone, username: null), credential: null, user: User(displayName: null, email: null, emailVerified: false, isAnonymous: false, metadata: UserMetadata(creationTime: 2021-12-30 12:22:29.000, lastSignInTime: 2022-01-18 09:01:18.000), phoneNumber: , photoURL: null, providerData, [UserInfo(displayName: null, email: null, phoneNumber: , photoURL: null, providerId: phone, uid: )],

What will I need to do to get some userinfo from Google (assuming that user has a Google account with that phone number)?

Answer (score 0):

When a user signs in to Firebase with the phone number provider, Firebase does not make any connection to any potential Google account with that same phone number.

If you need that information, consider signing in to **Google** itself with the phone number, and then using the resulting credentials from Google to sign into Firebase.

Comment: Frank, thanks for those directions. Will you be able to help point me to some resources on getting started with that approach?

Did you perhaps mean https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7222352 ?

The issue is that I want to use only SMS auth, as the user base I am targeting are more comfortable with SMS auth, and might not even be using email (which is actually becoming increasingly common in India).